# NoMethodError, has_many and belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive the following error.

```
NoMethodError in Users#show
...
undefined method 'contents' for #    <Article::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x43745a0>
...
<div class="col-md-6" style="background:yellow;"><%= @User.articles.contents %></div>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  ...
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    ...
  end

end
```

\users\show.html.erb

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background:orange;"><%= @user.title %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background:blue;"><%= @user.articles.count %></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background:yellow;"><%= @user.articles.contents %></div>
  </div>
```

added followings:

db\schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150720033506) do

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    ...
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "contents"
    ...
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.date     "user_date"
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Please advise me on how to avoid this error.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your full users/show.html.erb view and your schema.rb file.

Comment: please post schema for articles you can try `@user.articles.collect(&:contents)`

Comment: What is `contents` here?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @Pavan. I add `db\schema.rb`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Rajarshi Das. I tried and displayed the contents. But bracket and double quotation are added like this `["xxxx"]`. How do I remove bracket and double quotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `contents` method on a collection of articles.

Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="background:yellow;"><%= @user.articles.map(&:contents).join(', ') %></div>
```